# socket.io on openshift with angular-fullstack

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift, yeoman

I generated a node.js app using Yeomans angular-fullstack generator. 
Everything worked fine except the use of socket.io. After uploading my app to openshift using angular-fullstack:openshift, I got informed that I have to:

> Openshift websockets use port 8000, you will need to update the client
>   to connect to the correct port for sockets to work.
>           in `/client/app/components/socket/socket.service`: var ioSocket = io.connect('http://my-domain.rhcloud.com/:8000')"

I dont know where to do this. I am using socket.io version 1.0.6 which is shown inside package.json file.

> ==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
>   /var/lib/openshift/xxx/app-root/runtime/repo/server/config/socketio.js:41
>       socket.address = socket.handshake.address.address + ':' +
>                                                ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of null
>       at Namespace. (/var/lib/openshift/xxx/app-root/runtime/repo/server/config/socketio.js:41:46)
>       at Namespace.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Namespace.emit (/var/lib/openshift/xxx/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:205:10)
>       at /var/lib/openshift/xxx/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:172:14
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
>   DEBUG: Program node server/app.js exited with code 8
>   DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server/app.js'

By the way, the app, including socket.io, works fine on my local development machine!

Thanks for any help!
Fall.Guy

Answer (score 2):

My working solution is now:

I changed the creation of the openshift app to "not create a scalable app" (I disabled the -s switch in the yo angular-fullstack:openshift command)

After that, I changed the connection of socket.io to:

> ```
> var ioSocket = io('http://my-domain.rhcloud.com:8000', {
>   // Send auth token on connection, you will need to DI the Auth service above
>   // 'query': 'token=' + Auth.getToken()
> });
> ```

in the "/client/components/socket/socket.service.js" file.
Socket.io works now fine!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why openshift requires this, but you just need to modify your client code.

In your client side code, you should have something like this:

```
var socket = io();
```

You'll apparently need to update it to:

```
var socket = io('http://mywebsite.com:8000');
```

It's worth noting that there are plenty of other hosting providers (even free) which don't require you to jump through these hoops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didnt help me.
I still got the same errors.